# Dialog does not do autoposition

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I use dialog from jQuery UI. On my website, content of the dialog is changing dynamically (custom autocomplete of typed text). I already set css `max-height: 90%;` on dialog, so on a long content, dialog should be fully visible. But, when dynamic content as automplete is generated, dialog is resized, but still in same position, so 40% of content is not visible, it os out of screen. How can I fix that, when long content is generated, dialog will be autpositioned to the middle of screen?

**EDIT 1:**

Here is litle part of code from my website:

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: 'GET',
    'url': URL_SAVE.expandVariables({}, {
       'pres': self
    }),
    success: function(data) {
       var label = $('<label>Open file:<label>').appendTo(dialogElement);
       dt = data;
       input = $('<input type="text" />').appendTo(dialogElement).autocomplete({
          source: data,
          autoFocus: true,
          minLength: 0
       });
       dialog.open();
    }
 });
```

Here is demo, what is so similar to original [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/debute/P4vk5/)

**EDIT 2:**

This is initialization code for dialog:

```
var dialogElement = $('<div></div>'),
    input, dt, self = {
       serverEditor: server('editor')
    }, dialog = new Dialog(dialogElement, 'Open', {
       'saveable': 'Open',
       'width': 400,
       'saveOnlyIf': function() {
          return dt.has(input.val());
       },
       'ifNotSaved': function() {
          alert('Please choose correct file name!');
       }
    }).on('save', function() {
       $.ajax({
          'type': 'GET',
          'url': URL_SAVE.expandVariables({}, {
             'pres': self
          }) + input.val(),
          'success': function(data) {
             Presentation.unserialize(data);
          }
       });
    });
```

Comment: You should show us your code.

Comment: Yea, sorry, look at edit.

Comment: When you initialize the dialog, do you set height: 'auto', width: 'auto' ? Could you show us your dialog initialization code?

Comment: Here is a FIDDLE that allows any length of text (height: "auto") with a fixed width (width: 400). http://jsfiddle.net/AcG2Y/4/

Comment: Now I included initialzation code

Comment: I don't see anything obvious, perhaps if you try "fixing" the dialog by positioning it on the window or body with the top of the dialog at the top of an element at the top of the window.

Comment: In our company we decided to do another way to open user presentations. Anyway, thanks for help.